# What are the symmetries of a Trigonal trapezohedron?

Tags: geometry, dice, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

The asymmetric version of a [Trigonal Trapezohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonal_trapezohedron) is supposed to be a fair die just like a cube, meaning I can start with one face and rotate it about the center of the solid to get each of the other faces. I'm trying to get these rotations. Don't know how to go about this. Can someone help point me in the right direction? I want to know the axes I should use about which to rotate and the angles I should rotate about these axes.

Comment: It looks like a rotation of a third of a turn around an axis as well as flipping that axis. The net is simple enough where you could print it out and construct it to perhaps understand it better.

Comment: Been working on the net. But shouldn't a pure rotation exist about the center for transferring one face to each of the others?

Comment: Sure. The 3 where you flip that axis and rotate should be equivalent to a 180 degree rotation around some other axis. I'm basing this on the idea that the symmetry group is the same of that of a triangle, as the wiki article says.

Comment: Hint: consider the different types of rotation axes in a cube. Since the cube is a special case of the trigonal trapezohedron they should be identical. If you squeeze the cube into a trapezohedron, some of those axes remain axes of symmetry, while others will not be axes of symmetry any longer.

Comment: @RonaldBlaak I am very interested in this line of attack, but I've thought about it and it doesn't seem to work. For a cube centered at the origin, I can take the face facing down and rotate it about the y-axis by 90 degrees to get the front face. This doesn't work for the trapezohedron.

Comment: That is correct. A cube has 24 orientations (without reflections) that can be obtained by a rotation about some axis. Three of those axis go through the centres of opposite faces and have rotation angles of $\pm pi/2,\pi$, but there are two other types of axes (which ones?). The trapezohedron has 6 invariant orientations and only 4 axes of rotational symmetry. Note that a  rotational axis of a trapezohedron is (taking the deformation into account) also an axis of the cube, but the reverse is not true. It probably helps to make a drawing of cubes and find the different labelings of the vertices

Answer (score 0):

I got some help on Reddit (as well as the comments here) and managed to come up with this:

[image]

Here is the python code in case interested (courtesey etzpcm from Reddit):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageMath
#pip install raypy
from pyray.shapes.polyhedron import *
from pyray.axes import *
from pyray.rotation import *

m1= np.array([[1,0,0], [0,-1,0], [0,0,-1]])
t=2*np.pi/3
c=np.cos(t)
s=np.sin(t)
m2= np.array([ [c,s,0], [-s,c,0], [0,0,1]])
x0=2
y0=0.5
z0=1
z = z0*(-s*x0+(c-1)*y0)*x0/((c-1)*x0+s*y0)/y0
p = np.zeros((3,8))
p[:,0] = [x0,y0,z0]
p[:,1] = np.dot(m2,p[:,0])
p[:,2] = np.dot(m2,p[:,1])
p[:,3] = np.dot(m1,p[:,0])
p[:,4] = np.dot(m2,p[:,3])
p[:,5] = np.dot(m2,p[:,4])
p[:,6] = [0,0,z]
p[:,7] = [0,0,-z]
plane1 = np.array([p[:,i] for i in [0,3,1,6]])
plane2 = np.array([p[:,i] for i in [4,7,5,2]])
plane3 = np.array([p[:,i] for i in [0,3,7,5]])
plane4 = np.array([p[:,i] for i in [1,6,2,4]])
plane5 = np.array([p[:,i] for i in [2,5,0,6]])
plane6 = np.array([p[:,i] for i in [1,3,7,4]])
planes = np.array([plane1,plane2,plane3,plane4,plane5,plane6])
def draw_planes():
    for j in range(31):
        im = Image.new("RGB", (2048, 2048), (1,1,1))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im,'RGBA')
        r = rotation(3,np.pi/30*j)
        render_solid_planes(planes,draw,r,cut_back_face=True, scale=200)
        im.save(basedir + "im" + str(j) + ".png")
        im.close()
```